# PySpark Drop Rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

how do you drop rows from an RDD in PySpark? Particularly the first row, since that tends to contain column names in my datasets. From perusing the API, I can't seem to find an easy way to do this. Of course I could do this via Bash / HDFS, but I just want to know if this can be done from within PySpark.

Comment: use `filter` to filter out the bad rows

Comment: What if you want to just delete the first row? And let's say for the sake of argument, we can't use any information in the row vector x, i.e. we can't do `lambda x: (some condition using x)`.

Comment: Checkout my answer might be a bit closer to what you were looking for

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK there's no 'easy' way to do this.

This should do the trick, though:

```
val header = data.first
val rows = data.filter(line => line != header)
```

Comment: This is reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be data.first? data.take(1) will return an Array[T] with length 1.

Comment: This fails as soon as you may have duplicates in your list though.

Comment: @SebastianHojas As soon as you have your header in your data.  Further this works if you're reading multiple files with the same header.  Basically though, its not remove your first line, its remove any line that looks like your first line.

Answer (score 23):

Specific to PySpark:

As per @maasg, you could do this:

```
header = rdd.first()
rdd.filter(lambda line: line != header)
```

but it's not technically correct, as it's possible you exclude lines containing data as well as the header. However, this seems to work for me:

```
def remove_header(itr_index, itr):
    return iter(list(itr)[1:]) if itr_index == 0 else itr
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(remove_header)
```

Similarly:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda tup: tup[1] > 0).map(lambda tup: tup[0])
```

I'm new to Spark, so can't intelligently comment about which will be fastest.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on there (I'm a JS dev)? `return iter(list(itr)[1:] if itr_index == 0 else itr)`? 1) - `iter` takes an `(object[, sentinel])` - so I guess `iter` takes a list of `itr` iterables (rows), then uses Python's `range` operator, starting at the 2nd index (0 based), then iterates down until `itr_index == 0`, otherwise, keeps returning `itr` rows? I'm asking because I'm using the same thing but the initial row of fields isn't appearing, rather the first row of data becomes the fields.

Comment: The `iter` is maybe confusing the issue. If `rdd.mapParitionsWithIndex` returns the index of the partition, plus the partition data as a list, it'd just be `itr[1:] if itr_index == 0 else itr`- i.e. if it's the first partition (i.e. `itr_index == 0`) then exclude the first row (i.e. the header), and it it's not the first partition (i.e. no header), just return the whole partition. The `iter` and `list` are because it actually uses iterables instead of lists. As an aside, I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient route than `iter(list(itr)[1:])`.

Answer (score 5):

A straightforward way to achieve this in PySpark (Python API), assuming you are using Python 3:

```
noHeaderRDD = rawRDD.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda row_index: row_index[1] > 0).keys()
```

Comment: python3 doesn't allow tuple unpacking. So `lambda tup: tup[1] >0`  is better.

Comment: thanks @HSRathore, just updated the snippet code in order to avoid confusion for Python 3

Answer (score 3):

I did some profiling with various solutions and have the following

Cluster Configuration

#### Clusters

- Cluster 1 : 4 Cores 16 GB
- Cluster 2 : 4 Cores 16 GB
- Cluster 3 : 4 Cores 16 GB
- Cluster 4 : 2 Cores 8 GB

#### Data

7 million rows, 4 columns

```
#Solution 1
# Time Taken : 40 ms
data=sc.TextFile('file1.txt')
firstRow=data.first()
data=data.filter(lambda row:row != firstRow)

#Solution 2
# Time Taken : 3 seconds
data=sc.TextFile('file1.txt')
def dropFirstRow(index,iterator):
     return iter(list(iterator)[1:]) if index==0 else iterator
data=data.mapPartitionsWithIndex(dropFirstRow)

#Solution 3
# Time Taken : 0.3 seconds
data=sc.TextFile('file1.txt')
def dropFirstRow(index,iterator):
     if(index==0):
          for subIndex,item in enumerate(iterator):
               if subIndex > 0:
                    yield item
     else:
          yield iterator

data=data.mapPartitionsWithIndex(dropFirstRow)
```

I think that Solution 3 is the most scalable

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think just using a filter to get rid of this stuff is the easiest way. But per your comment I have another approach. Glom the RDD so each partition is an array (I'm assuming you have 1 file per partition, and each file has the offending row on top) and then just skip the first element (this is with the scala api).

`data.glom().map(x => for (elem <- x.drop(1){/*do stuff*/}) //x is an array so just skip the 0th index`

Keep in mind one of the big features of RDD's is that they are immutable, so naturally removing a row is a tricky thing to do

**UPDATE:**
Better solution.
`rdd.mapPartions(x => for (elem <- x.drop(1){/*do stuff*/} )`
Same as the glom but doesn't have the overhead of putting everything into an array, since x is an iterator in this case

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with spark2.1. Let's say you want to remove first 14 rows without knowing about number of columns file has.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
lines = sc.textFile("s3://location_of_csv")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
parts.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda tup: tup[1] > 14).map(lambda x:x[0])
```

withColumn is a df function. So below will not work in RDD style as used in above case.

```
parts.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id()).filter(index > 14)
```

Comment: parts and lines both are RDD's

`parts = parts.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda tup: tup[1] > 14).map(lambda x:x[0])`
as `parts.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda tup: tup[1] > 14).map(lambda x:x[0])` doesn't make changes inplace.

Comment: this worked for me. 
 notice the slight change in filter params. 
 Thanks!  ```parts.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id()).filter(col('index') > 14)```